# Swift class conforming to protocol, how to pass it as a parameter?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two classes, a view controller and a custom class. I have a protocol defined in the custom class, and my view controller conforms to that protocol. Now, I want to be able to, from my custom class, call the view controller's conforming methods whenever I want to. I thought I could do it the way Java handles interfaces where I pass the view controller object to the custom class, then call that object as needed. Here's my code:

To try to achieve this, I pass the view controller object as a parameter into the `BLEScanner.getInstance()` method:

```
var scanner = BLEScanner.getBLEInstance(this)
```

But Xcode keeps giving me this error:

> Cannot invoke getBLEInstance with an argument list of type (FirstViewController).

How do I pass my view controller object as a `BLEScannerProtocol` to the `BLEScanner getInstance` method?

**BLEScanneer code:**

```
@objc public protocol BLEScannerProtocol
{
    func someTypeMethod() -> Double
}

public class BLEScanner : NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate,ZestMsg_ZestMsgCallback, DataManager_DataManagerResponse {

    var tagDictionary = [String:IflexBluetoothTag]()
    let tagTimeoutIntervalSeconds = 60

    public func ResultWithNSString(data: String!)
    {
    }

    public func ResponseWithNSString(rsp: String!) {
    }

    private static var  centralManager : CBCentralManager!
    private static var sensorTagPeripheral : CBPeripheral!
    private static var mDataManager = DataManager()!
    private static var debugFirstMsg = false;
    private static let sharedInstance = BLEScanner()
    private var currentProtocol:BLEScannerProtocol!

    public override init() {
        println("Instantiated BLEScanner")
    }

    private static var isRunning = false;
    func getBLEInstance(media: BLEScannerProtocol) -> BLEScanner
    {
        if (!BLEScanner.isRunning)
        {
            BLEScanner.instantiateBLEScanner()
            let qualityOfServiceClass = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND
            let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
            dispatch_async(backgroundQueue,{

                BLEScanner.mDataManager.Start()

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    println("Test")
                })
            })
        }
        //

        return BLEScanner.sharedInstance
    }
}
```

**And here's my ViewController**

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, BLEScannerProtocol {

    var items: [String] = ["We", "Heart", "Swift"]
    var centralManager : CBCentralManager!
    var sensorTagPeripheral : CBPeripheral!
    var scanner : BLEScanner!

    @IBOutlet weak var songLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func playPauseAction(sender: UIButton) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var scanner = BLEScanner.getBLEInstance(self)
        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    }

    func someTypeMethod() -> Double
    {
        println("Instantiating BLEScanner")
        return 5.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use generics and generic contstraints.

```
func getBLEInstance<T: BLEScannerProtocol>(media: T) -> BLEScanner {
    media.someTypeMethod()
}
```

This says the function takes a generic type, but one that implements BLEScannerProtocol.

EDIT for request in comment.

You can achieve what you want, you'll just need to move the generic type up to the class level and create a property to hold the view controller. Here is a simplified example.

```
protocol BLEScannerProtocol {
    func someTypeMethod() -> Double
}

class BLEScanner<T: BLEScannerProtocol> {
    var media: T!

    func getBLEInstance(m: T) -> BLEScanner {
        media = m
    }

    func someOtherMethod() {
        media.someTypeMethod()
    }
}
```

Notice that media either needs to be an optional or implicitly unwrapped optional since it can't have a value set during init.

Comment: Hmm that helps, but I was hoping to have it so I could save the viewcontroller as an object inside the BLEScanner, so that whenever the BLEScanner has something useful to report, it will just call media.someTypeMethod()

Comment: I edited the answer to do what you are requesting. You could also use an optional and do optional binding on media if you would prefer the safety.